# GitVersion Mainline - Version increment on every push

Tags: gitversion

I am using GitVersion with Mainline mode. With default settings, it increases patch number with every commit in master. Is there a way to increase patch number on every push rather than on every commit?

If I push 3 commits together, patch gets increased by 3. In this case I would get version jump from 2.0.4 to 2.0.7 on VSTS build.

GitVersion.yml

```
mode: Mainline
```

Note: I have got only one branch, which is 'master' and I will be keep pushing my changes to master directly. I am not looking to use any branching strategy yet.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you have two options avaliable to you.

You could override `increment: None` for your `master` branch configuration:

```
branches:
  master:
    increment: None
```

But then, I think you would always need to "manually" bump the version of your code through git commits, such as including in your commit message: `+semver: (major|minor|patch)`, or updating your `GitVersion.yml` file to set the `next-version` configuration. This, I think, defeats many of the benefits of using GitVersion at all. But, this is still better than *not* versioning at all!

However, saying that you're doing "mainline" development, does not necessarily mean that you only develop in the master branch. I believe that mainline development mainly implies that you release off of the master branch (i.e. you're not using GitFlow with two long-lived branches, `master` and `develop`) and that the state of `master` at any point in time is deployable to production.

So you could achieve what you're looking for using two different branches as **@prestonsmith** already said in his answer. You and your team could work in short-lived topic branches off of master, and eventually merge (either normal merge-commit to preserve history, or squash merge (loses branch history and just introduces a single commit into master with all the changes created on the topic branch). This would result in the default behavior of a single patch version increment, which could later be changed to a minor or major increment via the use of git tags or, in your merge commit message, adding something like `+semver: (major|minor)` to instead increment the major or minor version number.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no - sorry :(

However, if you did decide to simply use two branches, you could simulate this by using Git's "Squash and Merge" strategy to achieve it. Basically, all of your commits would become a single commit on the main branch (master) after merging.

Feels simple enough to warrant it as a suggestion :)